# jQuery Navigation Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi We're creating a site offering support to specific causes and need a little help with jQuery when we open a navigation the div opens and when i go to open another navigation the previous one opens and the new one opens so we end up with two panels being open and the animation going again here is our code below, is their a better way to do this also...

```
//File Information - File Name/tser.min.js - File Distributor/Thomas Clark Counselling LTD
$(function() {
    //Notification Animations
    $(".notify-slide").slideDown(1000);

    //Mega Menu
    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "toggle-active" );
    });
    $('#dropdown-shop').on('click',function(){
        $('.dropdown-mega-shop').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#dropdown-help').on('click',function(){
        $('.dropdown-mega-help').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

& the HTML for the header file is

```
<header>
<?php
    include 'cookie-control.php';
?>
<div class="tc-nav">
    <div class="tc-etn-bar container">
        <div class="tc-bar-row">
            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo 'Return to ', $title, ' Home'; ?>"><div class="tc-logo-main"><?php echo $title; ?></div></a>
            <ul class="tc-main-nav">
                <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="dropdown-shop" onClick="return false" class="dropdown-toggle">Schedule an Appointment</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="dropdown-shop" onClick="return false" class="dropdown-toggle">Meet the Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="dropdown-help" onClick="return false" class="dropdown-toggle">Help & Support</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Dropdown Menus -->
<?php include 'mega-navigation.php'; ?>
<!-- Alerts -->
<div class="notify-slide alert warning-alert no-margin">
  <div class="container clearfix">
  <strong>£10 deposits &amp; up to 50% off - </strong>Ends 4th August<a id="close-alert" href="#">&times;</a></div>
</div>
<!-- End Header -->
</header>
```

& mega-navigation.php is

```
<section id="main-dropdown-menus" class="aria-alpha">
    <div class="dropdown-mega dropdown-mega-shop light">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-mega dropdown-mega-help light">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-mega dropdown-mega-products light">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown-span">
                <li class="heading">A Heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why the three document ready statements? Why didn't you combine them and add the mega menu code to it? Also, where's your HTML?

Comment: @j08691 sorry about that I've improved the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
   $(".toggle-active").removeClass( "toggle-active" );
   $( this ).addClass( "toggle-active" );
});
```

You don't need to use toggle, you can easily use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`

Then toggle visible div

```
$('#dropdown-shop').on('click',function(){
  $('.dropdown-mega:visible').slideToggle();
  $('.dropdown-mega-shop').slideToggle();
});
$('#dropdown-help').on('click',function(){
  $('.dropdown-mega:visible').slideToggle();
  $('.dropdown-mega-help').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: When I click the navigation link to close the panel it just closes and then reopens ?

Comment: Toggle might not be best, just change the `slideToggle` to `hide()`/`show()`

Comment: but we like the animation effect?

Comment: Easily addable by using parameters like duration and/or easing. For more effects include jQuery UI,which adds more UI features.

Answer (score 0):

The idea: Each time you `click`, `slideUp()` All other nav items, But not the current.

for example:

```
$(".nav-item").click(function() {
    $(".nav-item").slideUp(1000); // first slide up All other elements
    $(this).slideToggle(1000); // slide up/down 'this'
});
```

**demo:** (for example!) **http://jsbin.com/vatefeki/1/edit**